# Show sourcemaps in Chrome network tab

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, source-maps

I am starting to use source maps for my SASS code for debugging in Chrome.

The way I understood it to work was that Chrome requested in the stylesheet resource and the .map resource, yet I only see the stylesheet showing up in the network tab.

I know it's there and I know it's working as I can see the extra information from the source map in the elements tab and sources tab.

I also know I don't explicitly *need* to see it in the network tab as it won't load if the user doesn't have the flag set in developer tools, but I expected to see it loaded as a normal request like everything else, since I imagine it gets loaded in like every other resource? I guess it's just peace of mind to be shown absolutely everything being loaded in. I'm trying to make a highly performant site and I don't really wan't to be in the dark about requests the browser is making!

So, is there any way to get source maps to show in the network tab?

Comment: Yeah, I literally asked myself the same question today, why don't the `*.map` files show up in the network tab. I'm guessing Chrome simply removed that 'feature', because it looks like it definitely used to work that away, especially since I've seen many posts referencing it work that way. Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610098/how-to-use-source-map-to-find-minification-error

Comment: There is a way to view detailed network information. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41571230/1429301

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of a change that was mentioned here (perhaps not directly as a solution to this ticket, but discussed here):
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362913

The basic thinking is that source maps aren't actually part of the regular page resources, and the goal of the network pane is to show you what a normal page load would involve. So, bottom line: no, there is no way to force the maps to load.

Comment: And this is horrible because when they don't load properly you have no way to debug.

Comment: As they actually specifically acknowledge in that ticket: "This only makes debugging why a map isn't being served slightly harder if that ever comes up."

Comment: This thread showed that there is a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524221/source-map-is-not-visible-at-chrome-network-tab

Comment: @Timidfriendly And it's gone...