# Source map is not visible at Chrome network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Before Google Chrome update I saw source map files at Chrome Devtools on Network tab. Now, after update to version `43.0.2357.134 m` I don't see them.

Maybe my code is wrong? Or it's done intentionally to hide those source maps?

Comment: Did you open an issue for this?

Comment: No. If you wish you can do that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a way to get this information by searching for "map" in

`chrome://net-internals/#events`

[image: chrome://net-internals/#events]

Comment: IMHO this newer answer is more helpful than the accepted one, thanks.

Comment: "The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. " - I just tried to navigate to that page

Answer (score 6):

This was a side-effect of fixing [bug 362913](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362913) which was a feature request being tracked in [issue 465032](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465032).

If you have a need for seeing the map files then please file a [new issue](http://crbug.com/new) for it and explain the use-case for why you need it.

Answer (score -2):

If the source map worked, in dev tools:

1. The name of the source map file is at the end of your minified source file:
   [image]
2. When you open a source file ([Cmd + O] or [Cmd + P]) by definition that means that it could be mapped, and you can see from which file at the bottom of the source editor:
   [image]